# Replace newline chars with space in python

Tags: python, salesforce

Am using SQL to get the data from salesforce api using python.

The output is writing into csv file.

When I tried with the below statement, to replace the newlines, its not replacing all of them. For example, for one record we are getting multiple lines of data in multiple fields, leads to lot more records, instead of actual records that to in a wrong format.

```py
tmp.append(str(record['Description']).replace('\r\n',''))
```

[Used this link to write the json data into csv](https://www.mydatahack.com/salesforce-api-with-simple-salesforce-for-python/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: Python already has a [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module that makes it easy to read and write CSV files taking care of all formatting and quoting for you. Use it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use pandas to read the data?

you can do

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('filepath.csv', sep=',')
```

or you can do

```
pd.read_json('data.json', orient='records')
```

Do any of these work?